# PHP - pattern to reuse same behavior across class methods

Tags: php, oop, methods, class-method, code-reuse

I'm writing a service class that wraps up calls to some api endpoint using Guzzle.

I ended up writing those methods with basically identical Guzzle exception handling, i.e.:

```php
class ServiceClass {

    public function getMethod(){
        try {
            $response = $guzzleClient->get("some/url");
            // some business logic
            return $data;
        }
        catch(ClientException $e) {
            // handle exception
        }
        catch(RequestException $e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }

    public function postMethod(){
        try {
            $response = $guzzleClient->post("another/url", [/* some data */]);
            // other business logic
            return;
        }
        catch(ClientException $e) {
            // handle exception
        }
        catch(RequestException $e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Since every endpoint behave the same despite being a POST or a GET, i.e. in case of errors they returns the exact same response body structure (e.g. errors array), I'm wondering if there is a way to kinda "extends" every methods to reuse the same `try-catch` logic and isolate relevant individual business logics.

Comment: What you are doing _inside_ the catch blocks could come from an include, or be a function/method call - but you can't "split" the try-catch itself. What you could instead do - if you do not consider this too ugly - is write _one_ method that gets the request method passed as a parameter, and then makes a ["variable method call"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) on the $guzzleClient instance. But if you need to pass different amounts of parameters, that also still would need handling somehow.

Comment: @CBroe I already tought a couple of solution, and one is this, but it tomorrow Guzzle add another exception class to handle I still would need to edit any method to update the `catch`section. I'm not saying it is not a valid solution, I'm just saying I?m looking for a better one if it exists.

Comment: I suggest to read about the *Template Method* behavioral design pattern. Your problem can be solved by using standard Object Oriented Programming (OOP) techniques. There is no need to duplicate the exception handlers.